# Flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2

Tags: flutter, indexing, range, flutter-test

So I'm building a BottomNavBar using Google Nav Bar and after I index 4 pages, and when I clicked on the third page, it returns an error saying RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2
`

```
import 'package:egarment2/pages/master_page.dart';
import 'package:egarment2/pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:egarment2/pages/report_page.dart';
import 'package:egarment2/pages/user_home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import '../menu_card.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _navigateBottomBar (int index) {
    setState((){
      _selectedIndex = (index);
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    UserHome(),
    MasterPage(),
    ReportPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
          child: GNav(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            activeColor: const Color(0xFFf65d46),
            tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[200]!,
            gap: 8,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            onTabChange: _navigateBottomBar,
            tabs: const [
              GButton(icon: Icons.home, text: 'Home',),
              GButton(icon: Icons.dataset, text: 'Master',),
              GButton(icon: Icons.description, text: 'Report',),
              GButton(icon: Icons.person, text: 'Profile',),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

I seem to be stuck here since I'm a beginner in the mobile dev world, can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, i havent been able to reproduce your error. It works perfectly fine in my side.

Comment: onTabChange returns an index value. Pass that index value to your _navigateBottomBar Code: onTabChange: (index) {
                _navigateBottomBar(index);
              },

Answer (score 0):

In the `onTabChange` , use it like this :

```
onTabChange:(index){
       _navigateBottomBar(index);
       }
```